# convert binary to IP-address

Tags: ip-address

The binary string below should be a (hidden) IP-address in any way. How do I convert it to decimal? Since the number contains too many octets I dont know how to convert it. It should lead to this IPv4: 83.226.175.75

binary string:     001101110011010001110101001100000100010001101011011010100011001001010001

but it makes no sense! The first 8 bits in the string refers to decimal 55, and the IP-address should begin with 83. can we find a general rule to link this length of binary numbers to an IP address? Well, it cannot be IPv6, the string is to short...

Comment: It may be encoded in some fashion, but that isn't obvious.  Where does this come from, and why do you believe it contains an IP address?

Comment: ...seems you've answered your own question, too long for v4, too short for v6; therefore an assumption (perhaps, "it is an IP address") must be wrong :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

An IP address is either IPv4 : 32 bits or IPv6 : 128 bits.

Thus your binary string is NOT an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. They don't match.

Decimal IP notation is just an easier way to represent a binary IP. You can change a decimal IP to a binary IP and back, but there is no other way for them to magically convert to other numbers.

---

[To convert a decimal IP to binary](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20convert%20decimal%20IP%20to%20binary&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), we split up the four octets, and convert each decimal number to its binary representation.
So for your IP, 83.226.175.75:

- 83 → 01010011
- 226 → 11100010
- 175 → 10101111
- 75 → 01001011

Put them all back together, and your binary IP is 01010011111000101010111101001011. Notice that's a totally different binary number than what you've got. In particular, it's much shorter.
(And it's not contained anywhere within your binary number.)

---

To convert from binary to decimal, we do the opposite (which you started): break it into 8-bit chunks and convert each one to its decimal representation.
If we try to convert your binary number to a decimal IP, we get this:

- 00110111 → 55
- 00110100 → 52
- 01110101 → 117
- 00110000 → 48
- 01000100 → 68
- 01101011 → 107
- 01101010 → 106
- 00110010 → 50
- 01010001 → 81

If we put those decimal numbers together like an IP, it would be 55.52.117.48.68.107.106.50.81. That's clearly not an IP. It could be two IPs, smushed together, plus an extra octet, but that's not something I'd expect to encounter in networking.

---

Perhaps if you tell us where that string came from, somebody can give you a better idea what it means